# Accessing text of the element using invoke() in each(). Cypress

Tags: cypress, each

Want to access a text from the group of the elements.
this approach doesn't work, the runner is giving an error saying that invoke is not a function

```
cy.get('div[class^="lalala"]')
          .each(function($sec, i, $sects)  {
            $sec.find('header[class^="tatata"]')
            .invoke('text').then((text) => {
             let secText = text
             cy.log(secText);
         });
        })
```

But without each() it is working when I am accessing any of the elements:

```
cy.get('div[class^="lalala"]').first()
          .find('header[class^="tatata"]')
          .invoke('text')
          .then((text) => {
             let secText = text
             cy.log(secText);
         });
        })
```

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 2):

`$sec` is a wrapped jQuery element and `$sec.find()` returns a jQuery element as well. You have to use [`cy.wrap`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap) to call [`invoke`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke) on it.

```
cy.get('div[class^="lalala"]').each(function ($sec, i, $sects) {
  cy.wrap($sec.find('header[class^="tatata"]'))
    .invoke('text')
    .then((secText) => {
      cy.log(secText)
    })
})
```